# How to save a chrome extension as .exe file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cmd

I have implemented a chrome extension project but I need to install it by running a .exe file.

I tried many ways like extracting files to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions automatically using iExpress(i gave the id of extension to the folder),

i tried creating ExtensionInstallForceList under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Google\Chrome\ and creating new string value "1" giving it value "id;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"

and lots of other ways but still I couldn't make it. I would appreciate a little help

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I live in Turkey, the users in here have habits which makes nosense. When my company searched the statistics of inline installations and directly web store installations, the results were very low. So we decided to create a .exe file which can install extension and add it to oour website. We will see if the usage of extension will increase or not @DanielHerr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only programmatic way to install an extension on Windows (assuming you're not a Windows Domain sysadmin, which seems to be a safe assumption) is as follows:

1. Upload your extension to Chrome Web Store and publish.
   **This is mandatory**, but the extension can be specified to be unlisted.
2. Create an installer that adds a registry entry [as described here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry).
3. Upon next browser restart, Chrome will:

   - Download the extension from Web Store (and nowhere else)
   - Ask a confirmation from the user to allow that extension.
4. If the user agrees, you're done. If the user does not agree, the extension is *blacklisted* and you can't try again on this install unless the user installs directly from Web Store.

`ExtensionInstallForceList` is **only** for enterprise deployments via group policy. Chrome will ignore local registry values and query the domain policy directly.

Comment: how can i find the crx file's link? Do google give the link when i publish my extension on Chrome Web Store? @Xan

Comment: You don't need to provide a direct link. You need to know the ID (and the Web Store will assign you one when you upload, even before you publish), and `https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx` is a fixed update URL for _all_ extensions on the store.